# How install Xcode in windows 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm a Junior Mobile Developer, I want to install xcode in a Windows 7, or similar software. Anyone know a solution ?  For Android I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but there is no xcode for windows

#### xcode is mac only and needs osx 10.7+

Comment: Do you know other solution? Why I work with Windows

Answer (score 0):

you can not install XCode in a Windows, but you can use OS X through vmware in a Windows and then you can install XCode in OS X.

Comment: Thank you but I need a solution to work only on Windows 7.

Comment: you just can not install XCode in Windows 7 without a virtual machine.

Comment: Ok. But there are other similar programs?